# Split array of files in N chunks

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, typescript, chunks

I have an array of files and I have to split it in chunks based on the file size, in this way:

**[10MB image, 5MB image, 5MB image] with max size of 20MB wouldn’t really require split but [10MB, 10MB, 15MB] would be split to [10MB, 10MB] and [15MB]**

Then I have to function that takes the files and put them into a formdata to send it to the endpoint.

what I want to do is to return an array of `FormData` containing the chunks needed.

How can I achieve to that?

this is the current function:

```
const newImagesToEndpoint = (newFiles: NewImagesInterface[]) => {
    const newImages = new FormData();
    newFiles.forEach(img => {
      newImages.append('images[]', (img.file as unknown) as File);
    });
    return newImages;
  };
```

Comment: Can you clarify what "return n FormData" means? I've read and reread that second to last line a few times and it's a bit confusing. Haven't you computed the chunks already?

Comment: an array of FormData, so if the initial array will be split in 3 chunks i will have an array of 3 FormData objects

Comment: Oh, I see, you still need to implement the chunking. What have you tried already on your own?

Comment: i created a const "maxSize" to check when it's bigger than the limitFileSize and put the files into the formData, but i don't know how to take the rest of the files and put it in another one. i guess that's not the correct way to achieve it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question isn't that clear. I understand what you mean by split is send from client to server via multiple http calls, but not split an individual file ?

Assuming `NewImagesInterface` has a `size: number` field, something like this then ?

```
function sendChunks(images: NewImagesInterface[], limit = 20e6): FormData[] {
  const out: FormData[] = [], chunkSize = 0;
  for(const img of images) {
    if(img.size > limit)
      throw new Error('each individual image must be < ' + limit);
    if(!out.length || chunkSize + img.size > limit) {
      chunkSize = 0;
      out.push(new FormData[]);
    }
    out[out.length-1].append('images[]', (img.file as unknown) as File);
    chunkSize += img.size;
    return out;
};
```

Also please pay attention to types, that's the main point of typescript after all. If you want to output an array of `FormData` then the return type of your function must be `FormData[]`. The means your function will have at some point to build and return an array. If you think like that, starting from the type requirements and applying them to how you build your code, it will help you come up with a solution.

Comment: sorry if i couldn't make it very clear, but you got the point, im trying out your solution, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here's an algorithm I came up with quickly. It's a bit of a greedy algorithm, sorting by size DESC, and then iterates the sorted array and "packs" files into arrays with remaining availability. It finally maps the intermediate results to arrays of just the chunks.

***Note:** Obviously you will need to tweak this to *actually* consume your file arrays and correctly compute and compare file sizes.*

```js
const MAX_CHUNK_SIZE = 20;

const chunkFiles = (filesArray) =>
  filesArray
    .slice()
    .sort((a, b) => b.size - a.size)
    .reduce((chunks, file) => {
      const chunk = chunks.find((chunk) => chunk.available >= file.size);

      if (chunk) {
        chunk.array.push(file);
        chunk.available -= file.size;
      } else {
        chunks.push({
          array: [file],
          available: MAX_CHUNK_SIZE - file.size
        });
      }
      return chunks;
    }, [])
    .map(({ array }) => array);

const filesToProcess = [
  [{ size: 10 }, { size: 5 }, { size: 5 }],
  [{ size: 10 }, { size: 10 }, { size: 15 }],
  [{ size: 10 }, { size: 3 }, { size: 7 }, { size: 10 }, { size: 15 }]
];

filesToProcess.forEach((files, i) => {
  const chunks = chunkFiles(files);
  console.log(JSON.stringify(chunks));
});
```

These file chunk arrays can be passed to your `newImagesToEndpoint` utility.